# React native TouchableOpacity onPress event not working calling from other class

Tags: react-native, touchableopacity, onpress

What I wanted to do was create a `TouchableOpacity` once and use it everywhere in my program. I countered a problem when handling the press event. I imported the `TouchableOpacity` in other class and wanted to handle the onPress event there. But my code is not working.There is no problem with import as well.
Here is my class importing the `TouchableOpacity` component

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Text,View,Alert} from 'react-native';
import MyButton from './MyButton';

class FrontPage extends Component{
 OnPressNextButton=()=> {
   Alert.alert('You tapped the next button');
 }
 OnPressBackButton=()=> {
  Alert.alert('You tapped the back button');
}
  render(){
    return(
      <View style={styles.viewStyle}>
          <View >
            <MyButton  buttonText="Back" onPress={this.OnPressBackButton} />
            </View>
            <View style={styles.marginStyle}>
              <MyButton  buttonText="Next" onPress={this.OnPressNextButton} />
          </View>
        </View>
    );

  }
}const styles={
  viewStyle:{
    flexDirection:'row',
    borderWidth:1,
    borderBottomWidth:0,
    borderRadius:2,
    borderColor:'#ddd',
    shadowColor:'#000',
    shadowOffset:{width:0, height:2},
    shadowOpacity:0.2,
    marginLeft:5,
    marginRight:5,
    marginTop:5,
    elevation:1,
    position:'relative'
  },marginStyle:{
    marginLeft:128
  }
};
export default FrontPage;
```

and the `TouchableOpacity` component is created as

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import {Text,View,TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';
const MyButton=(props)=>{

  return(
    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.buttonStyle} >
      <Text style={styles.textStyle}>
        {props.buttonText}
      </Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
}
const styles={
  buttonStyle:{
    width:100,
    height:50,
    borderWidth:1,
    alignItems:'center',
    borderRadius:5,
    backgroundColor:'#fff',
    borderColor:'#007aff',
    shadowOpacity:0.8,
    marginLeft:5,
    marginRight:5,
    marginTop:455,
    position:'relative'
  },
  textStyle:{
    color:'#00f',
    borderColor:'#007aff',
    fontSize:20,
    paddingTop:10,
    paddingBottom:10,
    fontWeight:'600'
  }
};
export default MyButton;
```

Comment: Where did you handle the `onPress` in your component? You did not.

Comment: That's what I am asking. Where and how do I handle onPress?

Answer (score 1):

You should pass `props` to `onPress` action in your `TouchableOpacity` component in this code i put the same name `onPress` callback in the `FrontPage` component you can change the name `onPress` callback in this component with you name you want

This should be in your `FrontPage` Component

```
return(
  <View style={styles.viewStyle}>
      <View >
        <MyButton  buttonText="Back" onPress={this.OnPressBackButton} />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.marginStyle}>
          <MyButton  buttonText="Next" onPress={this.OnPressNextButton} />
      </View>
    </View>
);
```

this is should be your `TouchableOpacity` component

```
const MyButton=({ onPress })=>{

  return(
    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.buttonStyle} onPress={onPress}>
      <Text style={styles.textStyle}>
        {props.buttonText}
      </Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks man. I got the idea. It should have been 
const MyButton=(props)=>{

  return(
    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.buttonStyle} onPress={this.onPress}>
      <Text style={styles.textStyle}>
        {props.buttonText}
      </Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
}